# What is the full form of awk?

Tags: programming, awk

What is the full form of awk?

I tried googling. Google doesn't answer me.

Comment: Google answers if you ask properly , http://goo.gl/QEqi9d

Comment: type `man awk` in terminal and read more about **awk**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [The GNU Awk Users Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Foreword) it stands for **Aho, Kernighan and Weinberger**.